# Magento 2 and Authorize.net invalid details

Tags: magento, payment, authorize.net

I run Magento 2.1.4 and I try to setup default payment Authorize.net Direct post. I put API login and transaction key, but for some reason my card details are not accepted (tried a couple of other cards as well)

Anyone knows why this happens?

[image]

Comment: Can you update this question to include more details? For example, at what point in the checkout process does the problem occur? I'm not sure if you mean that you can't get past the payment section because it keeps saying the CC is invalid of if you mean that you get an error when you click "place order" (and if you do, what is the error message?).

Comment: @Joe It happens when I click on Place order. The error message is on the screenshot "Please enter a valid card type number".

Comment: @marilena6 have you find the solution? I get exactly the same error in Authorize.Net